# Microsoft Virtual PC + FreeBSD

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Всем привет. Установил на компе Microsoft Virtual PC. Поднял на виртуальной машине FreeBSD. Но на компе одна сетевая карта. Как сделать, чтобы интернет был и на виртуальной машине и на самой машине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитать справку по виртуальным машинам, раздел "настройка сети". Вкратце - Вам нужен [virtual] NAT.

Comment: Спасибо. Я разобрался. Действительно, нужно было в настройках выбрать используемый адаптер. Плюс не могу поставить - очков не хватает)